# Redis limit on number of subscribed channels?

Tags: redis, py-redis

I am using the python redis package to interact with redis on my Mac. I start redis in another window by just running redis-server with no arguments. Then I try to subscribe to about 80 channels using the redis pubsub object. I get connect messages back numbering from 1 to 63, but after that I keep getting connection message 63. Listing the subscribed channels shows me that it can only subscribe to 63 channels. Why is this? Is there a config setting that I can change to allow me to subscribe to more than 63 channels? How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you used `MONITOR` after you reach 63 subscribed channels to see what's going on inside Redis ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Redis doesn't limit the total number of channels that a single client can subscribe. Could you paste the error message and the version of  Redis and your python redis package?